Old deck footings not aligned with posts. Replace footings or extend them?
I have a 12' x 8' deck about 2' off the ground. One side is attached to the house with a ledger board that is in good shape. However, at the other end of the deck the posts are rotting at the ground. They are 6" posts siting on the concrete. The concrete is at ground level. The concrete footings have a surface size of 12" x 10" with a depth of 24". Two of the three posts are not lined up with the concrete and are hanging off on the side sitting on top of soil.
Should I remove the concrete footings and replace them with 8" round concrete using a form? Or attempt to add onto the existing footings with some rebar and concrete?


Are they real footings, dug down or just some cement poured on the ground?

The concrete goes down about 2 feet.

Do the 6" posts run up through the deck to become part of your railings?

They did. Don't know if I will do that again as I don't need the rail, but might.

Personally, I wouldn't mess with trying to add on to the existing footings. New concrete doesn't adhere well to old. You could pour new footings but if the current footings meet local codes for depth (here in Colorado it's 36" to get below the frost line) it might be easier to replace the rotted portions of your deck and reposition the posts to sit on the current footings.
It's difficult to give a good comprehensive opinion on that because of the limited scope of the picture. If you keep the support posts as part of your railing system you might cut off the posts flush with the bottom of the rim joist and through-bolt them to the cross joist and rim joist. Then use another short section of post positioned above the footing and through-bolt that to the rim joist centering it on the footing. If you do away with the railing just follow the same process for the  three support posts.
Structural stability will depend on having not only good support posts but a structurally sound rim joist. The rot I see in the picture may extend well up into the rim joist and it might also need replacing.
In addition, on a 12' x 8' deck two feet off the ground you shouldn't need 6" posts for support - 4" should do it. This would also make it easier to get all of the post on the footing.
Whether you dig new footings or not, you're still going to have to deal with replacing the rotted portions of the deck. Even if it's only the posts, that will still involve the railing. If the rim joist is compromised then it's even more labor intensive to remedy.
My point is, first determine what is required to get the deck structurally sound with the final design you want (railing/no railing). At that point you might have a lot more flexibility on the placement of the support posts, as described above.
Last, be sure to use a post base under each support post to help minimize future post rot.

